# Not show XML element if setter in JAXB Model was not executed

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb, boolean

The following JAXB Model is given:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public Customer {

   @XmlElement(name = "Name")
   private String name;

   @XmlElement(name = "IsVerified")
   private boolean isVerified;

   // Setter and getter for both attributes

}
```

I use this model for showing a REST resource in XML (GET request returns application/xml).
When `name` and `isVerified` were not set with the appropriate setters the XML element `Name` will not be showed in the resource, but `IsVerified` appears and has the value `false`. Is it possible to also not show the element `IsVerified` in case its setter was not executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Boolean instead of boolean
and add nillable

```
@XmlElement(name = "IsVerified", nillable='true')
```

Comment: After adding nillable=true the element IsVerified still appears.

Comment: are you sure that it is set to null?

Comment: Sorry, was my mistake. Just using Boolean instead of boolean works. Thx!

Comment: Conceptually, you should not use primitives if you do not want to show default values in output, use wrapper classes instead because they are initialized with NULL.